# Successful background before running scenarios - complete all retries before starting scenarios

Tags: karate

We recently ran into an issue, where our background call failed during the first attempt, which resulted in a failure for the first scenario in an outline, but was retried before the second run within the outline, and passed.

Is it possible to complete all retries, 3 by default, for the background, until success or all retries fail, before attempting any row in the scenario outline or scenarios within the feature file?

I would provide better images, but the background call for the first attempt failed, is obscured by the @setup scenario.
[image: report showing obscured background with failure]

Comment: I don't think this is supported currently, it may be if anyone contributes code